# How to Recover data from a field Vegalite?

Tags: vega-lite

How to recover a particular data from a field for display it?

During un mouseover on my point, I want data displayed.

I a new developer on `vegalite` for kibana platform on internship,  since I had time to read the doc and realize some visualizations, but I don't understand the deep running.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You might want to spend a bit more time with the documentation.  See https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/tooltip.html#vega-tooltip-plugin.